# Importing into role based price with wp all import

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the woocommerce plugin Role Based Price as we have two extra users thats price will get updated from a csv.

When i import using the WP All Import tool i specify the custom field i want to update with the function but all i get is a NULL value in the table.

Can someone please point out what i'm doing wrong here.

I assumed it was because the data in the manual update is a string and the values trying to import are integer

So in WPALLIMPORT it looks like this under the custom field option

```
Custom Field                        Value
_role_based_price                   [my_role_pricing({distributor_price[1]},{installer_price[1]})]
```

Then My Function

```
function my_role_pricing( $distributor_price, $installer_price ) {
$price_array = array(
    "distributor_customer" => array(
        "regular_price" => $distributor_price
        ),
    "installer_customer" => array(
        "regular_price" => $installer_price
        )
    );
return serialize( $price_array );
```

}

This is what my CSV looks Like

```
user_role;Code;regular_price
installer_customer;ProductCode;1000
distributor_customer;ProductCode;1500
```

The Mysql Table With Manually Set Role Prices Before Import

```
meta_key: _role_based_price
meta_value: a:2:{s:20:"distributor_customer";a:1:{s:13:"regular_price";s:4:"1100";}s:18:"installer_customer";a:1:{s:13:"regular_price";s:4:"1300";}}
```

The Mysql Table With Price After Import

```
meta_key: _role_based_price
meta_value: a:2:{s:20:"distributor_customer";a:1:{s:13:"regular_price";N;}s:18:"installer_customer";a:1:{s:13:"regular_price";N;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

i import distributor price in this way:

custom fields (in wp all import)

Normal price as normal price on WooCommerce add on (wp all import)

Name: _alg_wc_price_by_user_role_regular_price_rivenditori
Value: my price value for distributor

Name: alg_wc_price_by_user_role_per_product_settings_enabled
Value: yes

To find out what the name of the field containing the price is, first you have to manually enter the reseller price in the product, and then it appears in the list of custom fields of wp all import.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).